# Compound literals in IF statement

Tags: c, if-statement, compound-literals

I tried this small code to use compound literals in IF statement:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct time
{
    int hour;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct time testTimes;
    testTimes = (struct time){12,23,34};

    if (testTimes == (struct time){12,23,34})
        printf("%.2i:%.2i:%.2i\n", testTimes.hour, testTimes.minutes, testTimes.seconds);
    else
        printf("try again !\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It didn't work. it gave following message on compilation:

> prac.c:15:16: error: invalid operands to binary == (have ‘struct time’
>   and ‘struct time’)

Is it not allowed to use compound literals in IF statement or the syntax is not correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a good reason as to why you cant compare structures using the `==` operator

Quoting from [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/struct/compare.html)

> There is no good way for a compiler to implement structure comparison
>   (i.e. to support the == operator for structures) which is consistent
>   with C's low-level flavor. **A simple byte-by-byte comparison could
>   founder on random bits present in unused "holes" in the structure
>   (such padding is used to keep the alignment of later fields correct)**.
>   A field-by-field comparison might require unacceptable amounts of
>   repetitive code for large structures. Any compiler-generated
>   comparison could not be expected to compare pointer fields
>   appropriately in all cases: for example, it's often appropriate to
>   compare char * fields with strcmp rather than ==.
>
> If you need to compare two structures, you'll have to write your own
>   function to do so, field by field.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot compare structs using `==`.

You should compare each member of the struct separately.

Answer (score 1):

c provides no language facilities to do the == comparison of structs

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare structures. The standard (`C11 6.5.9 Equality operators`) states:

> `One of the following shall hold:`
>   `- both operands have arithmetic type;`
>   `- both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types;`
>   `- one operand is a pointer to an object type and the other is a pointer to a qualified or
>   unqualified version of void; or`
>   `- one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant.`

None of which apply to a `struct time`, unfortunately. You'll either have to check the fields individually with `==` and `&&`, or have a separate unchanging structure that you can compare with `memcmp`.

Although keep in mind that the latter suggestion may well run afoul of the padding information within structures, so the former is probably the best bet unless you *know* there is no padding.
.